# Reformat USB to remove "FDisk_partition_scheme"

Tags: mac, diskutil

I'm trying to reformat a USB Flash Drive so that it is readable by a tv. I have a USB that can be read and another that cannot be read. It seems the issue is the second drive has a "FDisk_partition_scheme". I cannot figure out how to remove this.

The first drive shown below CANNOT be read by my television while the second drive is readable.

[image]

Comment: I was able to get another Flash Drive to work with a similar output from above. Comparing the two drives it seems that one is "Removable" and the other "Fixed" when I run 'diskutil info' on each drive.